# Python - efficient approach to build an iterating mean

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, loops

I'm a Python user and I'm quite lost on the task below.

Let `df` be a time series of 1000 stock returns.

I would like to calculate an iterating mean as for below

```
df[0:500].mean()
df[0:501].mean()
df[0:502].mean()
...
df[0:999].mean()
df[0:1000].mean()
```

How can I write a efficient code?
Many thanks

Comment: you should give a sample of your data so we know what operations are valid

Comment: Hi Anon01, first of all thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has common transformations like this built in.  See for example:

```
df.expanding().mean()
```